# Is build_ Syntactic Sugar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntactic-sugar

I'm learning rails, and can't find a good way to search for this, as Google doesn't like underscores. What's `build_*` do as a prefix? Does it make an initializer for whatever model you attach it to?

Comment: You mean in assocations? Like `@post.build_author`?

Comment: Relevant API Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is related to associations. You can use it on a child class's object to build the parent association. You can't use it the other way around.

```
class Puppy
  belong_to :dog
  attr_accessor :name
end

class Dog
  has_many :puppies
  attr_accessor :name
end

p = Puppy.new(name: "baby")
p.build_dog(name: "John)
```

Comment: This is not correct. Maybe it was at the time of writing but now you can use `build_`to build a puppy https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference

Answer (score 1):

I came here to resurrect this in case anyone is looking for the same answer - Brainmaniac is right and the link he provided is updated. You can, in fact, do the other way around as well.
But instead of "build_", you will have to use something like:

In case of "has_one":
*@parent.build_children(parameters)*

In case of "has_many":
*@parent.children.build(parameters)*